# Enable/ Disable Combobox based on value of a textfield

Tags: extjs

I have a **textfield** and a **combobox**. I want the combo box to be enabled only if the **textfield** is not empty else disabled. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the idea how to enable and disable on bases of textfield value
  [here is the simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1mt0&view/editor)

hope this will help you and you will get your idea :)

Comment: Yeah exactly. Thanks for sharing the fiddle.

Comment: @Salman hassan OkZ -- I have the same requirement as as the original poster.  But I'm using v 3.3.1.  Any idea how to do the same thing using ExtJs 3.3.1?  I'm using a textfield and a combo box in the EditorGridPanel.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With [view model binding](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html)

If the textfield value is bound to a variable in the view model, that same variable can be bound to checkbox's disabled config.